# How to implement a structure array in class using matlab?

Tags: matlab, class, struct, structure

```
classdef myclass
    properties
        prop
    end

methods

    function obj=myclass(p)
        p=struct('field1',[],'field2',[]);
        obj.prop=p;
    end


    function r = plus(p,q)

        r.prop = p;
        r.prop = q;

        obj1 = myclass(struct('field1',[],'field2',[]));
        obj2 = myclass(struct('field1',[],'field2',[]));


        r = myclass(add(obj1.prop, obj2.prop));
    end 

end
end
```

this is my code. my structure array consists of fields:field 1 & field2. my class has a property: prop. I have made functions which uses struct and I want to use these functions under the class methods. How do I go about defining in the class that I will be using struct in the whole class?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're trying to use the constructor to initialise `prop` with a structure. Then you're using the `plus` method to add a new structure to `prop` as an array item. If this is what you're trying to do you could do it like this:

```
classdef myClass < handle
   properties
      prop
   end

   methods
      function obj = myClass(p)
         obj.prop = p;
      end

      function addItem(obj, q)
         obj.prop = [obj.prop, q];
      end 
   end
end
```

You can use this like this:

```
p = struct('field1',[],'field2',[]);
x = myClass(p);
x.addItem(p);
```

Then `x.prop` would be:

```
1x2 struct array with fields:

    field1
    field2
```

This class does not force the input values to be structs. You could do some checking and throw an error if the input value isn't of the required format.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the type of your properties in the properties definition block.

```
classdef myclass
    properties
        prop = struct
    end
end
```

If you then try to write another type to prop, e.g. a double value with `obj.prop = 2` in the constructor, there will be an error.